# I need a 301 htaccess redirect that will find files regardless of case

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We are moving to apache from IIS. IIS did not care about case, it served pages whether it was the user capitalized some words or not. But now I'm getting 404 errors all over the place. I need a 301 redirect that will automatically search for similar pages.

For example:

```
 NewHoMepage.htm
```

will redirect to

```
 newhomepage.htm
```

and

```
 News25/newnews.htm
```

will redirect to

```
 news25/NewNews.htm
```

Our site has 25 directories with 13,000+ pages, so a pages by page redirect is out of the question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this link: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html#RewriteMap_httpd-conf

Answer (score 0):

Found some interesting solutions here: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html.

Personally, I'd go with the second solution, by adding the following in the `.conf` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

As a side note, R=301 helps you from a SEO perspective, as search engines will update the links for your side and your pages will not be marked as duplicate content.

Comment: Would this affect all subdirectories, as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work for subdirectories as well. Whenever `apache` accesses resources from a  directory, it looks for   `.htaccess` files in that directory and it's parent/ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this short rule in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I imagine that I replace example.com with my url? Just checking. Better safe then sorry.

Comment: Starkeen, I tried this and accidentally forgot to replace example.com with my url. Now one of my links keeps redirecting to example.com. How do I fix this?

Comment: @starkeen, so this rule will convert an incoming url to all lowercase right? I think I may have to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Because each case is different, one cannot simply redirect to lower case.

As you have mentioned you don't want to do redirects for 13k pages, RewriteMap is also out of the question.

The general solution is to use `CheckSpelling on` in your `.htaccess` file. To be more specific, you could use `CheckCaseOnly on` instead.

Here's the documentation for `mod_spelling`:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html

Comment: I added 'CheckCaseOnly on' to my '.htaccess' file and the website gave me a 500 error. And ideas why? I'm on Dreamhost.

Comment: They must not have enabled `mod_spelling`. If you're not using shared hosting, you can enable it in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: it appears that Dreamhost does not support 'mod_speling' and has 'a2enmod' disabled. I'm planing to change all filenames to lowercase and as a rule to the htaccess file to change the incoming url to lowercase. I'm planning to do this on a folder by folder basis until I get all the files converted (ie, change the contents of a folder to lowercase and put a htaccess file in that folder with the lowercase rewrite.). Thoughts?

Comment: Probably the best way - general URL practice is to have everything lowercase and hyphenated.